# Setting a DateTime to the first of the next month?

Tags: c#

If I have `var olddate = DateTime.Parse('05/13/2012');`

and I want to get `var newdate = (the first of the month after olddate, 06/01/2012 in this case);`

What would I code? I tried to set the month+1 but month has no setter.

Comment: Your examples don't appear to be consistent. Can you explain if this is supposed to be 6th of January 2013 following fifth of December 2012?

Comment: @Oded sorry, I have it formatted American date style, mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: Made an edit so dates are not ambiguous to non US folks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this:

```
olddate = olddate.AddMonths(1);
DateTime newDate = new DateTime(olddate.Year, olddate.Month, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, olddate.Kind);
```

Comment: Ninja edits ftw. Remember to preserve the `DateTime`'s `Kind` as well. A lot of people ignore it, but if you ignore it and then pass your `DateTime` to code that doesn't, something unexpected could happen.

Answer (score 7):

This won't ever cause out-of-range errors, and will preserve the `DateTime`'s Kind.

```
dt = dt.AddMonths(1.0);
dt = new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, 1, 0, 0, 0, dt.Kind);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this simple one-liner:

```
var olddate = DateTime.Parse("05/13/2012");
var newdate = olddate.AddDays(-olddate.Day + 1).AddMonths(1);
// newdate == DateTime.Parse("06/01/2012")
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to define the Month and Year rightly, and after set the 1ª day. Try this:

```
// define the right month and year of next month.
var tempDate = oldDate.AddMonths(1);

// define the newDate with the nextmonth and set the day as the first day :)
var newDate = new DateTime(tempDate.Year, tempDate.Month, 1); //create
```

Answer (score 0):

lots of examples...pick your posion ;)

```
var olddate = DateTime.Parse("05/12/2012");

int currentDay = ((DateTime)olddate).Day;
//can always replace the while loop and just put a 1 for current day
while(currentDay != 1)
   currentDay--;

var newdate = (DateTime.Parse(olddate.AddMonths(1).Month.ToString() + "/" + currentDay.ToString() + "/" + olddate.AddMonths(1).Year.ToString()));
```