# With DateTime/DateOnly how can I determine 4th day of the month?

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to schedule sending a message with MassTransit and it accepts a `DateTime` object.

How can I say at a given point in time determine the 4th day of the month.

I initially thought new `DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month + 1, 4)` could work but what if you're in December? You'd have to check the month was 12 and then add 1 to the year value.

Is this an elegant way to do this?

Comment: Do you mean "the 4th day of the *next* month", or perhaps "the next upcoming 4th of any month, be it this one or the next"?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/13753193/395718

Comment: What is your expected result if you call this on `2023-01-01`, `2023-01-04`, `2023-01-07`, `2023-12-01`, `2023-12-04`, `2023-12-05` respectively?

Comment: Good points by @JeroenMostert. Using the accepted answer I extended it to see if DateTime.Now.Day < 4 and if so using current month else use AddMonths(1)

Comment: @Jon: Then you should edit your question if the requirement is not the same

Comment: With that particular requirement, you must also take into account edge cases like asking for "the next 31st of the month" or "the next 29th" (if these are possible), since these don't necessarily exist. That, in turn, also needs to cover the case where *today* is the day you're looking for (if that is possible). Date/time logic is an endless source of fun, for some values of "fun".

Comment: @JeroenMostert sure but I need the 4th so we should be ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about using `AddMonths()`

```
DateTime nextMonth = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(1);
DateTime result = new DateTime(nextMonth.Year, nextMonth.Month, 4);
```

Answer (score 2):

Not the greatest way, but you could use the `.AddMonth(1)` overload to get around the year problem

```cs
var date = DateTime.UtcNow;
DateTime fourthDay;

if(date.Day > 4)
{
    var nextMonth = date.AddMonth(1);
    fourthDay = new DateTime(nextMonth.Year, nextMonth.Month, 4);
}
else
{
    fourthDay = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 4);
}
```